# Is there an injective function such that $f(x^2)-f^2(x)\ge \frac{1}{4}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

The exercise asks me this:

Is there an injective function such that $f(x^2)-f^2(x)\ge \frac{1}{4}$?

ps: $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$

I really don't know how to start :c, I appreciate hints.

Comment: substitute $\sqrt{x}$ for $x$

Comment: Hint: Try computing $f(0)$ and $f(1)$. Note that $y - y^2 - \frac{1}{4} = -(y-1/2)^2$.

Comment: @Winther so it is not possible?

Comment: If $f$ is to be an injection then you cannot have $f(x) = f(y)$ if $x\not = y$. What do you get for $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ (see above and note that a square cannot be negative) and what do you conclude?

Comment: @Winther I don't know how to conclude, because I didn't knew I could call $f(x^2) = y$ and then $[f(x)]^2 = y^2$ because they're not exactly the same function

Comment: You can only do this for $x=0$ and $x=1$. If $x=0$ or $x=1$ then $x^2 = x$ and $f(x^2) = f(x)$ so $f(0) - f^2(0) \geq \frac{1}{4}$ which can be written $-(f(0) - 1/2)^2 \geq 0$. The same goes for $x=1$: $-(f(1) - 1/2)^2 \geq 0$. Why does this imply $f(0)=f(1)=1/2$?

Comment: @Winther but how does this prove that there is or there is not such function? Sorry, I can't understand :c

Comment: An injective function has the property $f(x) = f(y)$ only if $x=y$. We have shown that $f(0) = f(1)$ (and $0$ is not equal to $1$) so $f$ cannot be an injective function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such injective function. To solve it we first see that if $x^2 = x$ (which is the case for $x=0$ and $x=1$) then $f(x^2) = f(x)$ and $f(x^2) - f^2(x) \geq \frac{1}{4}$ becomes (for $x=0$ or $x=1$)

$$f(x) - f^2(x) - \frac{1}{4} = -\left(f(x)- \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \geq 0$$

but this is only possible ($-a^2 \geq 0$ implies $a=0$ since a square cannot be negative) if $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$. We must therefore have $f(0) = f(1) = \frac{1}{2}$ so $f$ cannot be an injection (since for an injective function $f(x) = f(y)$ implies $x=y$).